# How i can repair my redirect in php when my db is completed?

Tags: php, redirect

i have a problem with my redirection.

```
<?php

   

// Inclure les fichiers d'initialisation

require_once("../inc/init.inc.php");

require_once("../inc/haut.inc.php");



 ob_start();



// Assurez-vous que l'intervention_id est passé en paramètre dans l'URL

if (isset($_GET['id_intervention']) && is_numeric($_GET['id_intervention']))

{

    $intervention_id = intval($_GET['id_intervention']);

   

    // Récupérez les données existantes de la base de données

    $selectStmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT heure_debut, heure_fin FROM intervention_site WHERE intervention_id = ?");

    $selectStmt->bind_param("i", $intervention_id);

    $selectStmt->execute();

    $result = $selectStmt->get_result();

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $heure_debut = $row['heure_debut'] ?? null;

    $heure_fin = $row['heure_fin'] ?? null;

    $selectStmt->close();



    // Extrait les deux premiers caractères pour obtenir l'heure

    $heure_debut_affichage = substr($heure_debut, 0, 5); // Format "HH:MM"



    // Vérifiez si le formulaire a été soumis pour l'heure de début

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST" && isset($_POST['heure_debut']))

    {

        // Vérifiez le jeton CSRF

        if (!isset($_POST['csrf_token']) || $_POST['csrf_token'] !== $_SESSION['csrf_token'])

        {

            // Jeton CSRF invalide, traitement de l'erreur (par exemple, redirection ou affichage d'un message d'erreur)

            header("Location: erreur.php");

            exit;

        }



        // Récupérez l'heure de début depuis $_POST

        $heure_debut = $_POST['heure_debut'];



        // Vérifiez si une entrée existe déjà dans la table intervention_site

        $selectStmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT heure_debut FROM intervention_site WHERE intervention_id = ?");

        $selectStmt->bind_param("i", $intervention_id);

        $selectStmt->execute();

        $selectStmt->store_result();



        if ($selectStmt->num_rows > 0)

        {          

            // Une entrée existe déjà, effectuez une mise à jour

            $sql = "UPDATE intervention_site SET heure_debut = ? WHERE intervention_id = ?";

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bind_param("si", $heure_debut, $intervention_id);



            if ($stmt->execute())

            {

                // L'heure de début a été mise à jour avec succès

                // Mettre à jour le statut dans la table interventions à "en cours"

                $statut = "En cours";

                $updateStatusStmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE interventions SET statut = ? WHERE id_intervention = ?");

                $updateStatusStmt->bind_param("si", $statut, $intervention_id);



                if ($updateStatusStmt->execute())

                {                    

                    echo "Mis à jour table interventions 1 ok ";

                    header("Location: intervention_journaliere.php");

                    exit();             }

                else

                {

                    echo "Erreur lors de la mise à jour du statut: " . $updateStatusStmt->error;

                }

                    echo "Insertion intervention site 2ok ";

                    header("Location: intervention_journaliere.php");

                    exit();  

                $updateStatusStmt->close();

            }

            else

            {

                echo "Erreur lors de la mise à jour de l'heure de début : " . $stmt->error;

            }

            $stmt->close();

        }

        else

        {

            // Aucune entrée n'existe, insérez une nouvelle entrée

            $sql = "INSERT INTO intervention_site (intervention_id, heure_debut) VALUES (?, ?)";

            $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

            $stmt->bind_param("is", $intervention_id, $heure_debut);



            if ($stmt->execute())

            {

                // L'heure de début a été insérée avec succès

                // Mettre à jour le statut dans la table interventions à "en cours"

                $statut = "En cours";

                $updateStatusStmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE interventions SET statut = ? WHERE id_intervention = ?");

                $updateStatusStmt->bind_param("si", $statut, $intervention_id);



                if ($updateStatusStmt->execute())

                {

                    echo "Mis à jour table interventions 2 ok ";

                    header("Location: intervention_journaliere.php");

                    exit();

                }

                else

                {

                    echo "Erreur lors de la mise à jour du statut: " . $updateStatusStmt->error;

                   

       

       

                }    

                    echo "Insertion intervention site 2 ok ";

                    header("Location: intervention_journaliere.php");

                    exit();

                $updateStatusStmt->close();            

            }

            else

            {

                echo "Erreur lors de l'insertion de l'heure de début : " . $stmt->error;

            }

            $stmt->close();

        }

    }



    // Générez un jeton CSRF et stockez-le en session

    $csrf_token = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

    $_SESSION['csrf_token'] = $csrf_token;

}

else  

{

    // Ajoutez un message d'erreur ou une redirection ici si nécessaire

    echo "Erreur : ID d'intervention non valide.";

    exit;

}



?>



<div class="container heure-arrivee-container"> <!-- Utilisez une classe spécifique pour le conteneur -->

    <h2>Validation de l'heure d'arrivée</h2>

    <form class="intervention-form heure-arrivee-form" method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <input type="hidden" name="intervention_id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($intervention_id); ?>">

        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($csrf_token); ?>">

        <label for="heure_debut">Heure d'arrivée :</label>

        <input type="time" id="heure_debut" name="heure_debut" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($heure_debut_affichage); ?>" required>

        <input type="submit" value="Valider l'heure de début">

    </form>

    <a href="intervention_journaliere.php" class="return-link">Retour aux plannings journaliers</a>

</div>



<?php

ob_end_flush(); // Affiche le contenu mis en mémoire tampon et désactive la mise en mémoire tampon

// Inclure le fichier de pied de page

require_once("../inc/bas.inc.php");

?>
```

The message "mise a jour table ok" and "insertion intervention" is displayed correctly.

In my another page the redirection work but here it dont. Do you now why ?

I try to change my redirection but it's the same

Comment: You cannot redirect via PHP after you've sent data to the user. You're most likely getting a message that says "Headers already sent"

Comment: None error code is received. My db is correctly implemented but no redirection. I have replace header by "echo <script> document.location..." and it work. Thank you for your help :)